# Generate random string from 4 to 8 characters in PHP

Tags: php, string, hash, random, unique

I need to generate a string using PHP, it **need** to be *unique* and **need** to be from 4 to 8 characters (the value of a variable).

I thought I can use crc32 hash but I can't decide how many characters, but sure it will be unique. In the other hand only create a "password generator" will generate duplicated string and checking the value in the table for each string will take a while.

How can I do that?

### Thanks!

---

Maybe I can use that :

```
  function unique_id(){
  $better_token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
  $unique_code = substr($better_token, 16);
  $uniqueid = $unique_code;
  return $uniqueid;
  }

  $id = unique_id();
```

Changing to :

```
  function unique_id($l = 8){
  $better_token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
      $rem = strlen($better_token)-$l;
  $unique_code = substr($better_token, 0, -$rem);
  $uniqueid = $unique_code;
  return $uniqueid;
  }

  echo unique_id(4);
```

Do you think I'll get unique string each time for a goood while?

Comment: Characters from what character set?

Comment: "checking the value in the table for each string will take a while" - not if you set an unique index on that column. Then you'd just have to check if the insert worked, and if not you regenerate the string and try again. Not saying that's a good idea though. Depends.

Comment: @DanMan: Yeah but if I have 1 000 000 entries, generate a string until one unique is found :S... LOL but for small quantities, I'll remember this ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want cryptographically secure random data as a string with letters and numbers only, you may want to use [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In short, I think you'll get a pretty good random value. There's always the chance of a collision but you've done everything you can to get a random value. uniqid() returns a random value based on the current time in microseconds. Specifying rand() (mt_rand() would be better) and the second argument as true to uniqid() should make the value even more unique. Hashing the value using md5() should also make it pretty unique as even a small difference in two random values generated should be magnified by the hashing function. idealmachine is correct in that a longer value is less likely to have a collision than a shorter one.

Your function could also be shorter since md5() will always return a 32 character long string. Try this:

```
function unique_id($l = 8) {
    return substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, $l);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with randomness is that you can never be sure of anything. There is a small chance you could get one number this time and the same number the next. That said, you would want to make the string as long as possible to reduce that probability. As an example of how long such numbers can be, [GUIDs (globally unique identifiers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) are 16 bytes long.

In theory, four hex characters (16 bits) give only 16^4 = 65536 possibilities, while eight hex characters (32 bits) give 16^8 = 4294967296. You, however, need to consider how likely it is for *any* two hashes to collide (the "birthday problem"). Wikipedia has a [good table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) on how likely such a collision is. In short, four hex characters are definitely not sufficient, and eight might not be.

<strike>You may want to consider using Base64 encoding rather than hex digits; that way, you can fit 48 bits in rather than just 32 bits.</strike>

Eight bytes is 8 * 8 = 64 bits.

Comment: Yeah but how I can Generate base64 ? The only thing I know about Base64, is that I can convert mp3 and images into strings and Firefox will show them :P (And thanks for the math course! I loove maths! XD {Really!})

Comment: Actually, looking at the code you posted more closely, you already are using md5 with the raw_output option, so I assume that your application is OK with any character from ASCII 0 to 255 (**including** null bytes). If that is in fact a problem though, then you could take the first six bytes of the MD5 and then base64_encode() them.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable passwords You can only make from **ascii** characters **a-zA-Z** and **numbers 0-9**. To do that best way is using only cryptographically secure methods, like **random_int()** or **random_bytes()** from PHP7. Rest functions as **base64_encode()** You can use only as support functions to make reliability of string and change it to **ASCII** characters.

**mt_rand()** is not secure and is very old.
From any string You must use random_int(). From binary string You should use [base64_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to make binary string reliable or bin2hex, but then You will cut byte only to 16 positions (values).
[See my implementation of this functions.](http://php10.000webhostapp.com)