# It's possible to set length on "UUID()"?

Tags: php, mysql, uuid

I use to generate unique & random string mysql function `UUID()`, it's possible to set length of this generated string? I need only 8 letters.

This insert i do with php insert function...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible with the UUID as others have mentioned since it has a defined pattern as specified by the [standard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid). However you can use this function in PHP, which will create the unique ids for you of letters and numbers

```
<?php
function generateUUID($length) {
  $random = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $random .= rand(0, 1) ? rand(0, 9) : chr(rand(ord('a'), ord('z')));
  }
  return $random;
}
```

Comment: ... will create a **possibly** unique id. Really it just generating a roughly random string, which in general will be pretty unique - its just not garenteed to be. Calling it a UUID is a misnomer.

Comment: @barryhunter:- Indeed thats why I have written in my answer `which will create the unique ids` or is unique id misleading?

Comment: Yes, thats misleading. You calling a unique it, when it isnt, is wrong. It MIGHT be unique, but quite possibly wont be. Your function generates a random(ish) string, not a unique id, and certainly not a UUID.

Answer (score 2):

From [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

> A UUID is a 128-bit number represented by a utf8 string of five hexadecimal numbers in aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee format

So, no - you cannot specify the UUID length because it has defined format. The only thing you can do is to substring value returned by `UUID` function.

Comment: Ok. thanke you for your reply, do you know probably, which way exist to generate 8 letter unique string? I tested with so much php functions but they are not correct because of mysql insert if i do it with "while" of 3000 times...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444877/generating-a-unique-random-string-of-a-certain-length-and-restrictions-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438760/generate-random-5-characters-string?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The alternative is to use PHP to generate your unique number.

Comment: Saying that something *is not possible* is a sentence that should be used with caution on a programers platform :)

Comment: Agreed :-) But it is not possible with this function, and simply getting the first 8 characters greatly reduces the uniqueness of the string and therefor not a valid solution in my opinion.

Comment: I also agree with that and added your comment to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The UUID is a standard implementation:

> Returns a Universal Unique Identifier (UUID) generated according to
>   “DCE 1.1: Remote Procedure Call” (Appendix A) CAE (Common Applications
>   Environment) Specifications published by The Open Group in October
>   1997 (Document Number C706,
>   http://www.opengroup.org/public/pubs/catalog/c706.htm).

Maybe you could use some functions like `rand`. To create something random. Or use php to generate 8 charachters. Check this topic: [Generate random string from 4 to 8 characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954599/generate-random-string-from-4-to-8-characters-in-php)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT LEFT(UUID(), 8) FROM dual
```

Adding comment from Cas Wolters:

> simply getting the first 8 characters greatly reduces the uniqueness of the string